# Is there any way to load .zprofile like file on tmux new command?

Tags: zsh, tmux

I'm just trying to pass current zsh environment to tmux session. I have `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` in `.zprofile`. I did like below.

Create a new session like below.

```sh
tmux new -d -s ipython ipython
```

Attache to the session.

Then check what environment variables it has.

```py
In [1]: import os

In [2]: os.environ.copy()
Out[2]: 
(No RUST_BACKTRACE environemnt.)
```

Apparently, the environment variable is not same as zsh's ones. Is there any way to make tmux load `.zprofile` or something like that kind of file?

Comment: I currently use this command. `tmux new -d -s ipython zsh -c "source .zshrc;ipython"`

Comment: If you create a child process, it inherits the environment from the parent. Verify,  by doing a `printenv RUST_BACKTRACE`), right before doing the `tmux`, that this environment variable exists.

Comment: Keep in mind the client/server architecture of `tmux`. The *server* inherits your environment when it is first started. After than, any new session inherits its environment from the *server*, not the environment of your *client* when you reattach. The `update-environment` session option lets you specify a list of environment variables which the client should request the server to update for that session.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @chepner in a comment, I added command below to `.tmux.conf` and everything seems working fine. Thanks!

```
run-shell "cat ~/.zprofile | sed -n 's/export *\\(.*\\)=\\(.*\\)/tmux set-environment -g \\1 \\2/e'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case I adjusted `$ZDOTDIR=~/.config/zsh` in my `~/.zprofile`. As a result, tmux was not able to find `.zprofile` since it was searching for it in the `ZDOTDIR` directory and not in `$HOME` anymore. I overcame that issue by placing a `.zshenv` file in my home directory and put `export $ZDOTDIR=~/.config/zsh` there. Subsequently, `~/.zprofile` moves to `~/.config/zsh/.zprofile` and that solved the issue.